# Using Vertx with spring-data-neo4j outside Spring container

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, vert.x

We have DAO layer which uses Spring data to communicate with Neo4j. Inside DAO layer, it uses the spring annotations `@Autowired`, `@Repository` etc. We have API Layer which is written in Vertx. DAO layer is used as a library inside the Vertx application. I am able to use `@Inject` to inject Models with help of Guice. However, the code block like `personDo.findByName('test')` fails because it is not able to connect to neo4j outside of spring env. Any suggestions or pointer on how to use spring data without spring application?

DAO layer

```
// PersonDao.java
@Repository
public interface PersonDao extends CustomerDaoCustom, BaseDao<CustomerDo> {
    Optional<PersonDo> findByName(String name);
}
```

Vertx Application:

```
import com.example.dao.PersonDao;
import com.example.models.PersonDo;
...

@Inject
private PersonDao personDao;
...

public void findPerson(ServiceRequest request, Handler<AsyncResult<ServiceResponse>> resultHandler) {
    String personName = "Sam";
    logger.info("Example: finding person with name={}", personName);
    Optional<PersonDO> personOpt = personDao.findByName(personName);
    personOpt.ifPresentOrElse(person -> {
      logger.info("\t Person found: {}", person);
      logger.info("\t Person UUID: {}", person.getUuid());
      logger.info("\t Details: {}", person.dump());
    }, () -> logger.info("\t Person with name={} not found", personName));
```

`personDao` is null instead of `org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.SimpleQueryByExampleExecutor@379ce046`

This can be achieved easily in API if I use the spring boot application to start my vertx service but I am trying not to use Spring boot in my API layer.

Comment: While there is no Vert.x example there, there are other examples of Spring Data Neo4j 6 with other non-Spring frameworks: https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-examples-and-tips/tree/master/examples. Hope that helps!

Comment: @fbiville, thanks for response, let me try that